# TelephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso() returning incorrect value for Britain. Getting UK, should be gb

Tags: android, iso

Sometimes, my users will return "UK" as the country code as opposed to "gb" when `.getNetworkCountryIso()` is called on a user in Britain. Is there a specific reason for this?

Also, are there any more known discrepancies? I do not want to hack in a single fix just for the UK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in 2002 the European Commission introduced and reserved a few new codes for ISO implementation.

They added both "UK" and "EL", for the UK and Greece, respectively.

I have yet to see an instance of "EL" show up, which is not strange given that the ISO-3166-1 decoding table has not yet marked it as 'reserved' [Source](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso-3166-1_decoding_table), however the Europa publications office explicitly states that "EL" exists. [Source](http://publications.europa.eu/code/en/en-370100.htm).

The UK/GB problem seems to stem from the iso publications office reserving UK, and the reporting of this location seems to only happen on UK Nexus 5 phones (personal tests) with Orange / EE SIMs.

So, theres plenty of ways to get around this if it becomes a problem (which it may be, for Google's IAB does not recognize "UK" as a valid locale). The main being simply catching these discrepancies with a map with keys being the invalid codes and the value being the corrections.